# how can I add new properties to objects by iterating them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an object like this:

```
let newPost = {
   title: "Post 1",
   Content: "New content"
}
```

by coding this way:

```
let newPost = {};

let postData = $(".post-data").each (function(index) {
    newPost.title = $(this).text()
    newPost.content = $(this).text()
})

    <h5 class="card-title post-data" data-title = "title">Post 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text post-data" data = "content">New content</p>
```

But I always get the following:

```
let newPost = {
   title = "New content",
   content = "New content"
}
```

Comment: Why is there an `.each()`? Get the `.text()` of `.card-title` and `.card-text` and not from `.post-data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you should look to update each individual property per loop iteration, not all of them at the same time. In addition you need to make the `data` attribute name consistent across all of the target elements so that it can be used as the key of the output object. With that in mind, try this:

```js
let newPost = {};
$(".post-data").each((i, el) => newPost[el.dataset.key] = el.innerText.trim());

console.log(newPost);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="card-title post-data" data-key="title">Post 1</h5>
<p class="card-text post-data" data-key="content">New content</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rory McCrossan! It worked that way, but I don´t really understand how It works. what does this let $el = $(el) mean?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. `let $el = $(el)` is declaring a variable named `$el` which contains a jQuery object with a reference to the `el` argument of the `each()`, which is the `.post-data` element in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .each().

```
let postData = querySelectorAll('.post-data')

let newPost = {title: postData[0], content: postData[1]};
```

But that's a pretty bad way to organize data.
let me explain to you why this is happening, and then see below a better way to organize it.

The reason you are getting:

```
let newPost = {
   title = "New content",
   content = "New content"
}
```

is because what .each() does is that it iterate your array of items and change it each time, both of them.
So what's happened is:

step 1: You create newPost

```
let newPost = {} - empty
```

step 2: first iteration, now the item (this) is the post

```
newPost = {title: "Post 1", content: "Post 1"}
```

step 3: second iteration, now the item (this) is the content.

```
newPost = {title: "New Content" content: "New Content"}
```

basically, you change them both in each iteration, this is why it will be stuck on the last one.

In case this is your website you are trying to get data from I advise you to use `<form>`, or put them both in the same div, obtain the div via querySelector and then obtain each one from another querySelector to the div you obtain at first, then use .textContent() to get the text from the node.

Same for if you are trying to scrape something.
If you are scraping a bunch of things, like a lot of posts then use the .map() on the array you get and construct the objects from there.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @eliezra236. It helped me understand why that was happening. Cheers!